# How to get a "Done" or "Back" button in an EKEventViewController when no having a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ekevent

I have a list of calendar events in my iOS app, that is to be opened in an EKEventViewController when clicked. Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EKEventViewController *eventViewController = [EKEventViewController new];
    eventViewController.event = [self.events objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [self presentViewController:eventViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The Event view correctly pops up from the bottom of the screen, but I have no way of going back to the list of events!

I am using a navigation controller (but no navigation bar!), so adding this code made me able to go back to the list:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EKEventViewController *eventViewController = [EKEventViewController new];
    eventViewController.event = [self.events objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventViewController animated:YES];
}
```

But this solution is not very elegant, because when I press the "Back" button in the event view, the navigation bar is not removed (it shows on top of my event list view) before the event view is all out of the screen.

How to fix this? The best option would have been to somehow got a back button in the event view that I could have used with the first code here (so I would avoid showing the navigation bar), and the view could just slide back to the bottom of the screen when pressed.

SOLUTION:
Ended up with the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EKEventViewController *eventViewController = [EKEventViewController new];
    eventViewController.event = [self.events objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    eventViewController.delegate = self;
    UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController new] initWithRootViewController:eventViewController];
    [self presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)eventViewController:(EKEventViewController *)controller didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventViewAction)action
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: maybe you can show modal or animate show it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you do not need to hide the navigation bar at all ! Can you explain more why you need to hide or show the nav bar ? This will be simple solution to hide or show the model view.

// EKEventListVC.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
            EKEventViewController *pms = [EKEventViewController new];
            UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                           initWithRootViewController:pms];
            [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

// EKEventViewController.m

```
- (void)addRightButton
{
    UIButton *rightButton = // make your button
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rightBtnActionDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
}
```

//

```
- (void)rightBtnActionDone:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

// Edited For EKEventKitUI

```
-(void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
         didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {

    switch (action) {
       case EKEventEditViewActionCanceled:
           // User tapped "cancel"
           break;
       case EKEventEditViewActionSaved:
           // User tapped "save"
           break;
       case EKEventEditViewActionDeleted:
           // User tapped "delete"
           break;
       default:
           break;
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

[Code Example](https://github.com/neilang/Countdown) -

Comment: I now tried the exact code you suggested in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Now the event comes up beautifully from the bottom, and at the top I have an Edit and a Done button! The Edit button works, but nothing happens when I press the Done button. How do I make this dismiss the viewController?

Comment: To clearify: EKEventViewController is a class from EKEventKitUI, so I don't know if I can add the two methods you were suggesting.

Comment: I have added new code and there is video tutorial from lynda as well - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqJQY1CEPH0

Comment: I'm using a EKEventViewController, not an EKEventEditViewController.

Comment: It apparently didn't work since I had forgot to set the delegate of the viewController. See updated code in the question text.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the navigation bar in both cases as it is the best place to put a back/close button in a controller with a view hierarchy that you don't control.

a) Modally:

- Adjust the `EKEventViewController` `navigationItem` and embed the controller inside a `UINavigationController`. Then present the later!

b) Push:

- Do not hide the navigation bar and let the automatic back button appear. If you want to have a different UI for a particular controller a) is the better way to go.

---

If you do keep the navigation bar on your presented controller you can add a dismiss button like this:

```
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" 
                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                             target:self
                             action:@selector(dismissController:)];
```

The just implement `dismissController:` in your presenting controller.

Comment: Could you explain how to do the first one -> a) Modally?

Comment: With `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Comment: I've been able to make the UINavigationController pop up, but when I click the "Done" button, nothing happens (that is, I cannot get back to the viewController that presented the UINavigationController)!

Comment: Well that depends what you do when you click it. You should somewhere call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`.

Comment: But how to detect that this button is clicked?

Comment: Set its action to call one go your object's methods. For instance to call `myDismissButtonWasTapped:(id)sender` on your presenting view controller.

Comment: Can you elaborate (some example code would be great)? Here's my code:
    EKEventViewController *evc = [EKEventViewController new];
    evc.event = [self.events objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                   initWithRootViewController:evc];

How to set the "Done"-button's method, and dismiss the UINavigationController when this happens?