# White bottom bar appears after pushing EKEventViewController on Navigation Controller and returning

Tags: ios, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, ekevent

I'm developing an app displaying a table of events that are fetched from the iOS Calendar. When a row in the table is clicked, I want to display the event info using an EKEventViewController. Here is what the table of events look like:
[image: EventList before push]
When an event in this list is clicked, I push an EKEventViewController using the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EKEventViewController *eventViewController = [EKEventViewController new];
    eventViewController.event = [self.events objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventViewController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

I get to the event information screen (exactly what I want):
[image: Event overview]

But when I now click the back button in the upper left corner I am met with this screen:
[image: Event list after push]

Notice the white bar at the bottom. To get rid of this bar I now have to kill the app, going back to the main menu and other parts of the app has no effect (every screen is just "shrunk" to fit into the now smaller space, probably because the use of auto layout).

This does not happen on iOS 7, where this white bar never appears, only on iOS 8 (8.2 tested). What is this bar and how to get rid of it?

EDIT: I notice that the "white" bar looks gray when the screenshot is posted here on StackOverflow, while it is definitely white on the device.

EDIT2: Picture of the constraints for the bottom button:
[image: layout]

Comment: had you add constraints?if yes..then post it...

Comment: Which constraints to you want me to post?

Comment: bottom panel constraints?bottom panel is flickering when you go to one controller to another right?

Comment: I cannot see the flickering, but will post a picture of the constraints right away.

Comment: ok..just check it ....can you please post detail of bottom space constraints...means double click on it post detail of that consrtaint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out what the white bar really was, but I ended up presenting the EKEventViewController modally instead, which works very well: [How to get a “Done” or “Back” button in an EKEventViewController when no having a navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698060/how-to-get-a-done-or-back-button-in-an-ekeventviewcontroller-when-no-having)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what is happening in this situation. I don't normally work with `UIToolbar`, which is why I didn't recognize this sooner, but `UINavigationController` has an optional toolbar and has a function `setToolbarHidden()`.

From the section [Displaying a Toolbar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

> A navigation controller object manages an optional toolbar in its view hierarchy. When displayed, this toolbar obtains its current set of items from the toolbarItems property of the active view controller. [...] If not all of your view controllers support toolbar items, your delegate object can call this method to toggle the visibility of the toolbar during subsequent push and pop operations.

So in `viewWillAppear()` of the view controller that pushes `EKEventViewController`, call:

`self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)`

and when pushing `EKEventViewController` onto the stack call:

`self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)`.

You can adjust the `animated` parameters to suit your taste.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to address this is through the storyboard. 
Create an ViewController Object on the storyboard
Make its class EKEventViewController (No code or class file needed)
Embed in a Navigation Controller. 
Create a detail segue from the view controller you wish to call the EKEventViewController to the NavigationController

Then use performSegueWithIdentifier("EKEventViewController", sender: sender)

Setup the prepareForSegue something like this....

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EKEventViewController" {
        let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! EKEventViewController
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        controller.event          = event
        controller.allowsEditing  = true
        self.splitViewController?.toggleMasterView()
    }
}
```